# Implement total savings function on a record type

Tags: f#

the TotalSavings() function on the record below has a code smell that I can't exactly detail. Is there a more readable alternative for implementing this function on a record type?

```
type ProvidersCharged = ProvidersCharged of decimal
type InsuranceSavings = InsuranceSavings of decimal

type ClaimsSummary = 
    { Claims:Claim seq
      ProvidersCharged:ProvidersCharged
      InsuranceSavings:InsuranceSavings 
    } member this.TotalSavings() = match this.ProvidersCharged with 
                                   | ProvidersCharged charged -> 
                                        match this.InsuranceSavings with
                                        | InsuranceSavings savings -> charged - savings
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are, indeed, a couple of code smells.

The first one is that `TotalSavings` is a type member, and not a function ;)

The other code smell is that you have the beginning of [arrow code](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrowAntiPattern) in your implementation.

I'd write it like this instead:

```
let totalSavings summary =
    let (ProvidersCharged charged) = summary.ProvidersCharged
    let (InsuranceSavings savings) = summary.InsuranceSavings
    charged - savings
```

Notice that you don't have to use the `match` keyword when doing pattern match. With single-case discriminated unions, you can also pattern match directly into `let`-bound values.

Normally, the brackets aren't necessary, but in this case they are, because e.g. `ProvidersCharged` is both a case constructor and a record label. If the case constructor had been unambiguous, you could have omitted the brackets, like this:

```
let Foo foo = bar
```

You can also pattern match directly in function arguments, but in this case, it becomes too verbose:

```
let totalSavings' { ProvidersCharged = ProvidersCharged charged; InsuranceSavings = InsuranceSavings savings; Claims = _ } =
    charged - savings
```

Notice how the record labels are automatically destructured here, using nested pattern matching: matching is done first on the record labels, then on the case constructors inside of the labels.

You'll also notice that I used a wildcard match on `Claims` because I don't care about that value.

Answer (score 0):

I took Mark's answer and refactored my original code to the following:

```
type ClaimsSummary = 
    { Member:IdCard
      Claims:Claim seq
      ProvidersCharged:ProvidersCharged
      InsuranceSavings:InsuranceSavings 
    } member this.TotalSavings() =
        let (ProvidersCharged charged) = this.ProvidersCharged
        let (InsuranceSavings savings) = this.InsuranceSavings
        charged - savings
```

I believe that TotalSavings is context specific to the record type. Thus, I made the decision to tightly couple the TotalSavings() "member" to the ClaimsSummary record type. Hence, I don't think this function would be used by any other clients based on the summary typed argument used.